# Advice using isDigit(char ch) for this purpose

Tags: java, char

My method as follows is `public boolean digitsValid(String s)`

I need advice on how to implement the `isDigit(char ch)` after the first `char[0]` so all characters after this are digits the code returns true or false as follows...

example :

```
return true if X34567

return false if X45f7h
```

Comment: could you be more clear? what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you would accomplish this. Goes through the string skipping char 0, and returns false if any character is not a digit. It checks using [Character.isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))

```
public static boolean digitsValid(String s) {
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you could also use a flag value, just to have one `return` and to avoid the `if` statement inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substring()` method to separate the first character from the rest and then try to parse into an `int`. Here's how:

```
public boolean digitsValid(String s){
 try{
  Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
 } catch(NumberFormatException e){
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```